# Cube cooling Fourier series coefficients

Tags: thermodynamics, cooling

I wanted to solve a heat equation for cube which has initial temperature of $100°C $ and is cooling to the temperature of $20°C$.

I calculated heat equation and I wanted get the coefficients $a_{n,m,l}$.

The conditions are $T(x,y,z,t)=20$ for all $(x,y,z)$ on the boundary of the cube and all $t > 0$ and $T(x,y,z,0)=100$ for all $(x,y,z)$ inside the cube. The equation which I tried to solve:

$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \alpha \left(\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial z^2} \right)$

The function I got

$T(x,y,z,t) = 20 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} a_{n,m,l} \sin\left(\frac{n \pi x}{a}\right) \sin\left(\frac{m \pi y}{a}\right) \sin\left(\frac{l \pi x}{a}\right) e^{-\alpha^2 \lambda_{n,m,l} t}$

I calculated

$$ a_{n,m,l} = \frac{8}{a^3} \int_{0}^a \int_{0}^a \int_{0}^a 80 \sin\left(\frac{n \pi x}{a}\right)\sin\left(\frac{m \pi y}{a}\right) \sin\left(\frac{l \pi x}{a}\right) dx \;dy \;dz \\ 
= -\frac{2560 \;sin^2\left(\frac{n \pi}{2}\right) sin^2\left(\frac{m \pi}{2}\right) (1-cos(\pi l))}{\pi^3 n m l} = \\
= 80 \left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right)^3 \frac{1}{nml} (1-(-1)^n)(1-(-1)^m)(1-(-1)^l)$$

But it seems not right. I don't know how to determine the right Fourier coefficient. I get this:

[image: It should be 100 for t=0]

Thank you for help.
I get this

[image: coefficient]

Comment: You have no boundary conditions: $T(x,y,z,t)=20$ simply means that $T=20$ for all $x,y\text{ and }z$ and for all of time. You need three BCs: one for $x$, one for $y$ one for $z$. W/o these your problem is ill-posed.

Comment: @Gert I explain the initial conditions.

Comment: You have a PDE, second order and in three dimensions (plus time). That means you need an initial condition (which you have) and TWO BCs per dimension, in order to be able to determine all integration constants (there are six of them).

Comment: I've corrected conditions for $x,y,z$, are they enough to find $T(x,y,z,t)$?

Comment: Yes, I'll formulate an answer now

Comment: I'm having it noted that the OP has substantially altered his question since it was first posed.

Comment: What should be equal to $a,m,l$ coefficient?

Comment: I will try and answer this tomorrow.

Comment: @Gert Have you tried to find what's wrong?

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong?

Comment: Is the plotted temperature at $(a/2,a/2,a/2)$?

Comment: @Gert Yes it is plotted temperature at (a/2, a/2, a/2). I think it should be $100$ for $t = 0$ and $20$ for some specific $t$, which is $t > 0$. It is cooling, so with higher $t$ temperature should be dropping.

Comment: Looks like a sign error in your $a_{n,m,l}$. The triple integral is banal though. I suggest you simply do it again with a 'fresh look' at it.

Comment: Plotting the first $40$ terms BTW, is excessive. The $\exp$ term decreases very, very rapidly with increasing $n^2+m^2+l^2$.

Comment: I calculated the integral and I didn't noticed the sign error. Why for t =0 it is not 100? I put calculation in the post

Comment: Calculating sums with more therms like 40 is closer to $\infty$, so it should be more accurate. The problem was with Mathematica precision. The function should be equal to 20 for infinite t? Is it right for cooling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your boundary conditions (BC) are better formulated as:
$$T(0,y,z,t)=T(a,y,z,t)=20$$
$$T(x,0,z,t)=T(x,a,z,t)=20$$
$$T(x,y,0,t)=T(x,y,a,t)=20$$
Such BC are called '*non-homogeneous*' and very difficult to handle.

But there's a 'cheap-and-easy' remedy: transform the dependent variable $T$ to:

$$u=T-20$$
The new boundary conditions in $u$ are now homogeneous, because:
$$u(0,y,z,t)=u(a,y,z,t)=0$$
$$u(x,0,z,t)=u(x,a,z,t)=0$$
$$u(x,y,0,t)=u(x,y,a,t)=0$$

All your derivatives remain the same because $20$ is a constant and derives to $0$.

The new PDE is now:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \alpha \left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2} \right)$$

Now you solve this PDE with the new, homogeneous BCs (the IC becomes $u(x,y,z,0)=80$) and when you're done you apply:

$$T(x,y,z,t)=20+u(x,y,z,t)$$

**That's where your mystery constant come from.**